# Send Navigation Audio to handset but music to bluetooth

Tags: audio, navigation

I have a DROID 3 and use it both for navigation and listening to music in my car via Bluetooth (Ford with SYNC). In the BT profile for SYNC on my phone, I can turn off media output over Bluetooth and get navigation audio over the phone but still make calls via BT. However, I would also like to have music and podcasts play over BT but still have navigation over the phone. Sometimes I will listen to a CD or radio and still want navigation, but when media output over BT is turned on, I con't get any nav audio, since the car is not switched to the BT media mode.

In older versions of Android Nav, the audio was not over the media channel so this wasn't a problem. Is there a way to switch it back so that nav audio is ALWAYS over the handset speaker?

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? This isn't an end all cure all but I have gotten what you wanted to work to work on the HTC Glacier using MIUI, so perhaps look into something along those lines if you're rooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio routing would have to be set in the application code itself.

However, direct audio routing [is deprecated since API level 5 (Android 2.0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Older versions of Android Navigation had this direct audio routing set to the [ROUTE_SPEAKER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ROUTE_SPEAKER) in their application code. But the newer versions of Android have a system wide flag set with [setSpeakerphoneOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29) or [setBluetoothScoOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn%28boolean%29) if it should use the speaker or bluetooth.

I'm afraid that you won't be able to change anything about your setup since it is all build into the system and application code. All sounds will be routed through the same audio output in the newer versions of Android and Android Navigation.